# How to host a React app created using "create react app" on nginx?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, web-hosting, package.json, nginx-config

I build the react app (which was created using create-react-app) using `npm run build` command. I added `"homepage":"./"` to the **package.json** file and build the project. (But I am not sure what should be written in `homepage` in the package json file)

Then I copied what was inside build folder to nginx's HTML folder after creating a new folder named 'sample' inside the HTML folder in nginx.

Then in the browser, I opened the URL `localhost:81/sample/`, but it's not working.

can someone please tell me the step by step process that I should follow to host my react app in nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First make sure Nginx is running on your port 8080 (or port 8081 in your case since you are hosting it there). I don't recall I have to add the homepage to package.json file. I just need to do `npm run build` then copy the build folder to /usr/share/nginx/html/. However, my project is Nginx with React on Docker.
- What operating system are you using? There is some tutorial showing step by step to host it on Nginx, for example, on Ubuntu: https://medium.com/@timmykko/deploying-create-react-app-with-nginx-and-ubuntu-e6fe83c5e9e7